# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.tensorboard.tensorboard'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

There seems to be a problem with recent TensorFlow build. The TensorBoard visualization tool would not run when it is compiled from sources to use with GPU. The error is as follows:

```
$ tensorboard
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gpu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/bin/tensorboard", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorflow.tensorboard.tensorboard import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.tensorboard.tensorboard'
```

Specs of system: Ubuntu 16.04, NVIDIA GTX 1070, cuda-8.0, cudnn 6.0.
Installed using Bazel from sources as described here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources

Installed into fresh anaconda3 environment 'tensorflow', environment is activated when performing command.

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

An easy fix:

```
python -m tensorboard.main --logdir=/path/to/logs
```

Answer (score 4):

After some trial and error, I have solved this issue by adapting the file `tensorboard-script.py` in `path/to/conda/envs/myenv/Scripts` (Windows) as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    #import tensorflow.tensorboard.tensorboard
    import tensorboard.main

    #sys.exit(tensorflow.tensorboard.tensorboard.main())
    sys.exit(tensorboard.main.main())
```

Now I can invoke tensorboard as expected:
`tensorboard --logdir=log/ --port 6006`

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I've found a solution that works and also received some explanation from tensorflower on github.

There might be an issue with tensorboard when compiling tensorflow from sources because tensorboard is now removed to a separate repo and is not a part of tensorflow. The tensorflower said the docs will be updated eventually, but I figured a workaround for the impatient (like myself).

Edit `tensorboard` file inside `tensorflow/bin` (`/home/gpu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/bin/tensorboard` in my case) and replace

`from tensorflow.tensorboard.tensorboard import main`

by

`from tensorflow.tensorboard.main import *`

Now tensorboard should run from console as usual.

Comment: Still getting the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.tensorboard'` :(

Comment: `python -m tensorboard.main --logdir=/path/to/logs` is helpful

Comment: And the link to github discussion: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10959

Answer (score 1):

Tensorboard ships with tensorflow. If you are unable to run using `tensorboard` command, try below approach. `tensorboard.py` might have been moved to different directory.

Try searching for `tensorboard.py` in the tensorbard directory where tensorflow is installed. Go to the path and use following line for visualization:

```
python tensorboard.py --logdir=path
```

Comment: The `tensorboard.py` file cannot be found anywhere. `tensorboard` folder inside `tensorflow` folder only contains `main.py`. However, when the following command `python main.py --logdir=path` is executed inside the `tensorboard` folder, tensorboard starts. It's great that I'm finally able to start it but I wonder, what caused `tensorboard` command to fail in the first place...

Answer (score -1):

You should priorly launch
    pip install tensorflow.tensorboard